# Add empty tags without selecting text in Emmet Vim

Tags: vim, emmet

When I start typing in normal mode and press `<C-y>,` it doesn't expand the content. Also, when I type in normal mode, the text doesn't show.

I know how to select some text and expand the abbreviation on it but I want to be able to add empty tags (basically creating a structure and then fill out the necessary components as I go).

Comment: Give a example of what you tried and tell the expected output as well. That will help others to answer the question questioned easily.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I wasn't following the correct procedure.

This is what I did.

1. Write some code to the file in insert mode (eg. `div>ul>li`).
2. Press escape and enter normal mode.
3. Press `<C-y>`

The following set of procedure will expand your expression into HTML tags.

NOTE: Make sure that the cursor is at the end of the expression (end of line) with your HTML code when you press `<C-y>`